# Integral of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

For $$u(x) = \begin{cases}  (1-|x|)^2, &|x|≤ 1,\\ 0, &|x|>0\end{cases}$$

I have the integral that gives the Fourier transform of $u({\omega})$

$$ 
\int_{-1}^{1} ((1-|x|)^2)e^{-ix\omega}dx $$ which is equivalent to the integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{1} ((1-|x|)^2)(e^{-ix\omega}+e^{ix\omega})dx 
$$

I want to understand how to obtain the second integral from the first integral.

I am trying to understand it better by finding a common Fourier transform

$\vert x\vert = -x$ for $x \lt 0$ and $\vert x\vert = x$ for $x\gt 0$:
$$
F_\text{trans}= \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} f(x) e^{-ikx}\,dx  =  \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} e^{-a|x|} e^{-ikx}\,dx \\
= \int_{-\infty} ^{0} e^{ax} e^{-ikx}\,dx + \int_{0} ^{\infty} e^{-ax} e^{-ikx}\,dx \\
= \int_{-\infty} ^{0} e^{(a-ik)x}\,dx + \int_{0} ^{\infty} e^{-(a+ik)x}\,dx.
$$

$$ \frac{e^{(-a-ik)x}}{-a-ik}\Big|_{0}^{\infty} +  \frac{e^{(a-ik)x}}{a-ik}\Big|_{-\infty}^{0} $$

$$ \frac{e^{-a\infty}e^{-ik\infty}}{-a-ik} + \frac{1}{a+ik} + \frac{1}{a-ik} - \frac{e^{-\infty a}e^{-\infty-ik}  }{a-ik}$$

Then I understand the first fraction goes to zero since dividing by a very large number ($\infty$ will obviously result in a very small number. Then the second fraction is just straightforward, so is the third. The fourth however knowing the result of this Fourier transform should also go to zero however I fail to understand how since it seems to become like $\frac{\infty}{\infty (a-ik)}$ due to the double - sign. Could someone please clarify this for me..?

Comment: If $x\ge0$  then $(1-|x|)^2=1-2x+x^2$. So you can calculate the second version of the integral using integration by parts.

Comment: I actually meant how to obtain the second integral from the first integral. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Break the integral into two integrals, one over $[-1,0]$ and one over $[0,1]$. Then try using the substitution $u=-x$ in $\int_{-1}^{0}((1-|x|)^2)e^{-ix\omega}\;dx$

Comment: Ok I'm struggling with where minus signs should go, to try and understand better I have found a partial solution to a similar question that I now have a question on which I will add to my original question.